# How do I enable RDS support for BlazeDS?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

I'm using BlazeDS 3 in my application. The dependencies for the BlazeDS libraries are downloaded from a public maven repository. However I can't enable the RDS support on the server because of some missing library. Does anyone know where this class is located:
flex.rds.server.servlet.FrontEndServlet
in the blazeds distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, reported fixed a couple of months ago ... For bug details - check [here](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-18612). Of course, this is in the nightly builds, not in the official release.

You'll notice in the bug text they refer to the fix being in ChangeList Number-229457.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use blazeDS 4 to get RDS support. The class that you are referring to 
`flex.rds.server.servlet.FrontEndServlet` is present in `flex-rds-server.jar` which is provided along with BlazeDS 4